# How to pull a docker image without checking locally?

Tags: docker

How can I pull an image without checking locally? I want to download it every time even if its available in local.  I added it `--disable-content-trust` flag but it still stays image is up to date.

```
docker pull --disable-content-trust my-image:<tag>

stable-2.12.3: Pulling from my-repo

Digest: sha256:1b9152b5d51ddd88b7b5b4234d6653d0ac0335e5cd32a74522a4fbc973fc7764
Status: Image is up to date for my-repo/my-image
```

Edited: added the tag.

Comment: i think use this command will achieve your goal: `docker pull my-image:<tags>`

Comment: @lemoana I have the image tag already, it wasn't added to the post. It still doesn't pull if it's available on local.

Comment: is the **IMAGE ID** your pulled same with the old image in your local? as i know,docker images is identified by **IMAGE ID**.thereis no way that two same IMAGE ID of docker images in server, unless they have different tags